# How to skip a video in an nth increment in OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I've been reading OpenCV documentation about reading and skipping on a video using trackbar, for example 10, the video will play at 10s, 20s, 30s...n. But I can't seem to implement it on the right way using Python. I just want to ask for your suggestion of an algorithm. If any, some snippets. Thank you.

Comment: Hi, can you show what you've tried so we can move from there?

Comment: call `video.grab()` 10 times, then `video.retrieve()` one time

Comment: have you heard of "seeking"? that's what the thing is called that you want to do to a video. be warned, it's often not exact or costs more CPU to make exact.

Answer (score -1):

You can make loop over video files and open every video[i] with step like in this code

```
import cv2

video_files = os.listdir(folder)

step = 10    ## every 5 video

### loop over videos show every 10..
for i in range(0,100, step):

     video_name = video_files[i]
     cap = cv2.VideoCapture('../folder/'+video_name)

     num_frames = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT))

     ### loop over video and show
     for i in range(num_frames):
          ret_prev, frame = cap.read()
          cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
          cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer sir, but my question were a bit ambiguous. It should be skipping thru video in every 10s. The video should play at 10s,20s, ....

Answer (score -1):

I'm have understood your comment
This is code to show just every 10s 20s  etc..

```
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('../folder/'+video_name)

num_frames = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT))
fps = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)

### loop over video and show
for i in range(num_frames):
          ret_prev, frame = cap.read()


      ### this we show every 10s other will be skip
          if i % fps*10:
            cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
            cv2.waitKey(0)
```